# Locating a google apps script months after you've saved it

Tags: google-apps-script

A while back I created a "Gmail Snooze" script from this Lifehacker article http://lifehacker.com/5825634/how-to-add-a-snooze-button-to-gmail-no-extensions-required

I'd like to make some edits to it now but I can't find it!  When I go into the script editor I have no saved projects to open.  Can anyone point me towards a method of finding this script that is running every night so I can edit it?

Answer (score 4):

The **File > Open** dialog usually only shows you the script projects that are attached to the spreadsheet you have open. If you [open the editor directly](https://docs.google.com/macros/) that menu should show you all the projects you own.

Comment: That's awesome!  I've had this problem before but was always able to find my script with a little looking.

Comment: @Eric Koleda : how did you manage to create that link that works for any user ? that's indeed a very useful tip ! I'm going to have to clean my collection one of these days ;-)

Comment: @Eric, Can you think of any reason why the link you posted [link]https://docs.google.com/macros/ doesn't show my recent scripts? I worked on one yesterday, but it doesn't show up. I'm assuming that the link should show those .gs scripts not in the current spreadsheet. I'm in the situation as the original poster, where I worked on a nice UI, prompted by Serge, but now can't find the spreadsheet container.

Comment: Since the launch of script.google.com, and the Drive integration, it looks like the behavior has changed, so that it now opens Google Drive instead.